# Systems of linear equations: Why does no one plug back in?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, systems-of-equations

When someone wants to solve a system of linear equations like

$$\begin{cases} 2x+y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases}\,,$$

they might use this logic:

$$\begin{align}
\begin{cases} 2x+y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} 
\iff &\begin{cases} -2x-y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} 
\\ 
\color{maroon}{\implies} &\begin{cases} -2x-y=0\\ x=4 \end{cases} 
\iff \begin{cases} -2(4)-y=0\\ x=4 \end{cases} 
\iff \begin{cases} y=-8\\ x=4 \end{cases}
\,.\end{align}$$

Then they conclude that $(x, y) = (4, -8)$ is a solution to the system. This turns out to be correct, but the logic seems flawed to me. As I see it, all this proves is that 
$$
  \forall{x,y\in\mathbb{R}}\quad
  \bigg(
  \begin{cases} 2x+y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} 
  \color{maroon}{\implies}
  \begin{cases} y=-8\\ x=4 \end{cases}
  \bigg)\,.
$$

But this statement leaves the possibility open that there is no pair $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfies the system of equations.

$$ 
\text{What if}\; 
\begin{cases} 2x+y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} 
\;\text{has no solution?}
$$

It seems to me that to really be sure we've solved the equation, we *have* to plug back in for $x$ and $y$. I'm not talking about checking our work for simple mistakes. This seems like a matter of logical necessity. But of course, most people don't bother to plug back in, and it never seems to backfire on them. So why does no one plug back in?

**P.S.** It would be great if I could understand this for systems of two variables, but I would be deeply thrilled to understand it for systems of $n$ variables. I'm starting to use Gaussian elimination on big systems in my linear algebra class, where intuition is weaker and calculations are more complex, and still no one feels the need to plug back in.

Comment: something that may be interesting to note is that, when solving large systems of linear equations on a computer (with finite precision), you may get the case that $A.\vec{x}-\vec{b} \neq \vec{0}$

Comment: When solving if the system of equations doesn't have a simultaneous solution you'll get a contradictory statement.  You'll end up with something like 0=1.

Comment: I've re-read this question 10 times trying to understand what this question means and why is it that reputed users have taken this question seriously and provided serious answers. I give up.

Comment: @Sridhar one possibility is that the questioner remembers from an earlier class that certain mathematical processes introduce extraneous solutions that must be tested.  For example, solving sqrt(x + 1) + 3 = 2x by squaring both sides.  It is easy for someone to just get into their head "you have to check your solutions, because your method, even though correctly applied, may give extraneous ones".  (See the discussion of that equation here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/74783.html )

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you get $x=4$ and $y=-8$ then how can the system of your equations not have a solution?

Comment: I suggest the title is misleading since many people do plug back in! What about "Systems of linear equations: Why is it not necessary to plug back in to confirm the solution is valid?" I think this better captures the nub of the issue here?

Comment: @Sridhar  Check out https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/unique-candidate-that-fails  for examples which will make OP's question seem more reasonable.

Comment: @Sridhar This is actually a good question. It's true that implication in only one direction wouldn't preclude this possibility.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You wrote this step as an implication:

> $$\begin{cases} -2x-y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} -2x-y=0\\ x=4 \end{cases}$$

But it is in fact an equivalence:

$$\begin{cases} -2x-y=0 \\ 3x+y=4 \end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} -2x-y=0\\ x=4 \end{cases}$$

Then you have equivalences end-to-end and, as long as all steps are equivalences, you *proved* that the initial equations are equivalent to the end solutions, so you don't need to "*plug back*" and verify. Of course, carefulness is required to ensure that every step *is* in fact reversible.

Answer (score 38):

The key is that in solving this system of equations (or with row-reduction in general), every step is *reversible*.  Following the steps forward, we see that *if* $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equations, then $x = 4$ and $y = -8$.  That is, we conclude that $(4,-8)$ is the only possible solution, assuming a solution exists. *Conversely*, we can follow the arrows in the other direction to find that if $x = 4$ and $y = -8$, then the equations hold.

Take a second to confirm that those $\iff$'s aren't really $\implies$'s.

Compare this to a situation where the steps aren't reversible.  For example:
$$
\sqrt{x^2 - 3} = -1 \implies x^2 -3 = 1 \iff x^2 = 4 \iff x = \pm 2
$$
You'll notice that "squaring both sides" isn't reversible, so we can't automatically deduce that $\pm 2$ solve the orginal equation (and in fact, there is no solution).

Comment: It would help if you clarified: which step feels "non-reversible", and why?

Comment: The one I wrote with the forward arrow instead of the double arrow, but now that you and @dxiv have called me on it, I see my mistake.

Comment: It had originally felt non-reversible to me because taking A=B and C=D and producing A+C = B+D is non-reversible, but I'm seeing that there's more to it.

Comment: To see that it is reversible: note that if we start from the right, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
A=B\\
C=D
\end{cases} \implies
\begin{cases}
A=B\\
C-A=D-B
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I actually just wrote something almost identical on my notepad! Yes, I see it now. The key is that the A = B sticks around after A + C = B + D is produced, and you can use it to get back to C = D.

Answer (score 21):

Elementary row operations do **preserve** the solution set, for [elementary matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix) are invertible.

We start with equations $2x+y=0$ and $3x+y=4$, which define the two lines depicted below

[image]

Subtracting $2x+y=0$ from $3x+y=4$, we obtain $x=4$, which defines a line parallel to the $y$-axis

[image]

Subtracting $x = 4$ twice from the equation $2x+y=0$, we obtain $y=-8$, which does define a line parallel to the $x$-axis

[image]

Note that all $4$ of these lines pass through the point $(4,-8)$.

Comment: It's not so simple as rotations because when you add a multiple of one equation to another you will never rotate the hyperplane described by the first such that it coincides with the hyperplane described by the second, unless they were already identical. I believe it's a shear but I didn't try to prove it.

Comment: I really like this visual approach. It helps to see what's going on behind the algebra.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: It's true that the elementary matrix is a shear matrix, but that does not obviously imply that the hyperplane defined by the equation that is being added to is sheared parallel to the hyperplane for the equation that is added. At least, I don't see an obvious link. Do you?

Comment: @user21820 You are correct. Thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer and deleted all talk of rotating or shearing. Thinking "visually" without rigorous verification leads to utter nonsense. I learned my lesson.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: You're welcome! In fact at the time I posted my answer I gave some thought to whether shearing could explain why the transform never changes the solution-set (it was my first guess), but when I failed I just didn't mention anything about it. If someone proves my guess or comes up with the right geometric explanation I'll be glad to know too! =)

Comment: @user21820 The matrix that transforms the line $3 x + y = 4$, which is parametrized by $\begin{bmatrix} t\\ - 3 t + 4\end{bmatrix}$, into the line $x=4$, which is parametrized by $\begin{bmatrix} 4\\ t\end{bmatrix}$, is $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Well to get the desired conclusion we would need a shear that is parallel to the modified hyperplane. The transformation that you give is not, so it unfortunately does not help.

Answer (score 14):

*dxiv* has already answered your question for your specific example. But if you want to know the general case, when doing Gaussian elimination you have three kinds of basic steps:

1. **Rearrange equations**: Clearly reversible.
2. **Multiply (both sides of) an equation by a non-zero constant**: Clearly reversible because of "non-zero".
3. **Add any multiple of one equation to another**: On a little reflection it is reversible too, since the operation can be easily undone by subtracting that same multiple of the first equation from the second.

This suffices to show that every step is reversible, and hence the system of equations has exactly the same solution-set after any sequence of basic steps. In fact, this is why you can sort of 'read off' the solution from the RREF of the original augmented matrix that represents the system of equations, because each basic step corresponds to left-multiplying the augmented matrix by an elementary matrix (which is invertible).

Comment: Step 3 is only reversible if the resulting equation isn't a tautology.

Comment: @KyleStrand Step 3 is surely reversible: the key is using two *different* equations (by their position, not by their form).

Comment: @egreg I understood what user21820 meant, but I was thinking that if the original system of equations were not linearly independent, you'd lose information somehow. But of course you're right: since the addend is unchanged, it can simply be subtracted from the tautology.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Indeed as egreg said. The key is that the information in the original system is equivalent to the information in the transformed system, and any dependence in the original will also be present in the final. The nature of the solution-set (no solution or unique solution or infinitely many solutions with $k$ independent parameters) can hence be read off the final RREF.

Answer (score 7):

All of the elementary/college textbooks I've seen do recommend checking solutions at the end by substitution. However, it's not strictly necessary because (as other answers point out) all of the steps involved are logical equivalences.

You should be aware of what the algebra looks like, for a system of two equations in two variables, when you're *not* in the situation of having exactly one solution to the system (i.e., an independent system). In these cases, when you add the equations together (your second step), **both variables will be eliminated**. In the case of a dependent system (infinite solutions), you will get an identity, e.g., 0 = 0. In the case of an inconsistent system (no solutions), you get a contradiction, e.g., 0 = 1.

For examples of this, consider [OpenStax College Algebra Section 7.1](https://cnx.org/contents/mwjClAV_@5.2:C7Haz2cb@4/Systems-of-Linear-Equations-Tw).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! Each step being an equivalence, on top of answering my question, also explains why reaching "0=0" guarantees an infinite number of solutions. That was something that used to bother me as well.

Comment: @user404789: This post is seriously misleading if not wrong. Consider the system of equations $\{ x=0 ; -x=0 ; x+y=3; x-y=1 \}$. Adding the first two gives $0=0$ but there are **no solutions**.

Comment: Added "for a system of two equations in two variables".

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Okay thanks for fixing! Personally I think one should focus on the structure of the RREF as the way to analyze solution-set types, since the behaviour is not so simple for systems of many equations.

Comment: @user21820 Ah, good counterexample. The logical steps get tough to keep straight when you've got an unusual system like that and you're approaching it in a kind of loose way. I think from now on I will stick to Gaussian elimination where (as you answered) every step is an equivalence!

Comment: @user404789: For solving general systems of linear equations, yes that's the way. Even for non-linear equations, one can manipulate the system reversibly by just keeping the originals along with whatever new equations one can deduce. Notice that this is equivalent to discarding the originals during deduction and later checking to see which of the solutions to the new system satisfy the original. But it is sometimes easier to use irreversible deductions to avoid cluttering the working, like for $\{ x^2+y^2=5 ; x-y^2=1 \}$. Adding gives a quadratic with roots $-3,2$, one of which works.

Answer (score 7):

Another point of view.  Gaussian elimination of a system of linear equations is equivalent to multiplication by certain types of **elementary matrices**.  To avoid getting bogged down I will give specific examples and get you to look up more general cases if you find it of interest.

There are three basic types of row operation.

> Add a multiple of an equation to another equation, say, $3$ times equation 1 to equation 2.  For example
>   $$\eqalign{x+2y&=3\cr4x-5y&=6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \eqalign{x+2y&=3\cr7x+\phantom{1}y&=15\cr}$$
>   This corresponds to multiplying the (augmented) coefficient by a certain matrix,
>   $$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \pmatrix{1&0\cr3&1\cr}\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}
>   =\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr7&1&15\cr}$$
>
> ---
>
> Multiply an equation by a non-zero constant, say, the first row by $-2$.  For example,
>   $$\eqalign{x+2y&=3\cr4x-5y&=6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \eqalign{-2x-4y&=-6\cr4x-5y&=6\cr}$$
>   corresponds to
>   $$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \pmatrix{-2&0\cr0&1\cr}\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}
>   =\pmatrix{-2&-4&-6\cr4&-5&6\cr}$$
>
> ---
>
> Finally, interchange two equations:
>   $$\eqalign{x+2y&=3\cr4x-5y&=6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \eqalign{4x-5y&=6\cr x+2y&=3\cr}$$
>   which corresponds to
>   $$\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}\quad\longrightarrow\quad
>   \pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr4&-5&6\cr}
>   =\pmatrix{4&-5&6\cr1&2&3\cr}\ .$$

And now the point: all three classes of multiplying matrices are **invertible**, and their inverses are matrices of the same types.  This means you can automatically get from your final equations back to the original, and checking solutions is not necessary.

However, while this works for linear equations, it does not in general work for other types of equations.  Your practice of checking solutions is absolutely correct and very important - please don't stop doing it!!

Comment: Thanks for writing out an example that illustrates the last paragraph of my answer, and for emphasizing that we cannot in general reverse algebraic manipulations! =)

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to see that there is a solution; Notice that the equations are linearly independent. We only have three cases: either the lines are on top of each other, are parallel but a constant vertical distance apart, or cross each other at some point. Linear independence let's us know we are not dealing with case $1$ and we can just as easily plug in points to check case $2$, so only case $3$ is left. We could also just solve for $y$ and remember some basic algebra.

Answer (score 1):

In my research I work with very large systems of linear equations. On the rare occasions that I have to work out a small system of equations by hand, I absolutely plug them in to check their correctness. Mistakes by hand are easy. When I am using a computer to handle the matrices that represent these equations, I generally trust that the computer did it correctly. I have other checks on my answers other than plugging them back in.

The second part of your question was, how do we know that the solution is unique? How do we know that there aren't other correct answers? We know this because they are linear equations. Two non-parallel lines intersect at a point. A line and a parabola can intersect at a point, two points, or not at all. This isn't a formal proof, but it should give you an idea.

To generalize this to multiple dimensions, a single linear equation in n dimensions describes a sub-space with dimension n-1. For the 3-d case, this is a 2-d plane inside that 3-d space. The solution to that system is the space where every equation intersects. The intersection of 2 spaces that have dimension n-1, has dimension n-2. For our 3-d example the intersection of two planes is a line (dimension 1).
If you have n unknowns, you know that you need n equations in order to have a unique solution. This can be explained by the fact that each equation reduces the dimension of the solution set (the number of variables), by one. When the dimension of the solution set is zero, the solution set is a point. Points are a unique solution.

I hope this helps, I have a odd way of thinking about linear algebra that confuses some of my colleagues.

Comment: A little unrelated, but this is helpful I guess...

Comment: I actually found this quite helpful indeed! It revealed a lot about the fabric of mathematics. In particular, linear algebra and such equations.